# Angular and PHP

Tags: php, html, angular, http, post

I have been searching for this problem online and found many similar questions but no answer which helps me.

I have my frontend written with the help of Angular with the following form:

```
    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
        Course Acronym: <br><input type="text" name="acronym"><br>
        Name: <br><input type="text" name="name"><br>
        Points: <br><input type="text" name="points"><br>
        Course coordinator: <br><input type="text" name="coordinator"><br>
        About: <br><input type="text" name="about"><br>
        Year given: <br><input type="text" name="year"><br>
        Study period: <br><input type="text" name="period"><br>
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

As of now I'm trying to echo the variables onto /welcome.php with the following script:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your coordinator is: <?php echo $_POST["coordinator"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

But all this gives me is the error message: Cannot POST /welcome.php
It's all run in the localhost:4200.

What do I need to do to make this work or read up on to get a better understanding of how it works? Thanks!

Comment: The error message is literally just "Cannot POST /welcome.php"? Where does that error come from? Are there any more details? There's no Angular involved here as far as anyone can see.

Comment: Check that your web service is up and running and configured the right way. This seems to be no PHP-side error for me.

Comment: About the mention of angular: Just wanted to give an overview of the setup. Yes, it's the only error message I get and it comes with a refreshed page with the URL: http://localhost:4200/welcome.php

Answer (score -1):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport

This is what we used to connect Angular frontend to Laravel backend.
You'll send objects to the API then manage your routing to have it reach your Controllers.

My senior is really the one who connected Angular to Laravel but I hope this would help you out.